Determining Flow Orchestration Version from a Flow Interview
I am trying to find a way to determine the running flow version of an orchestration using the Flow Interview Id.
When looking at the Flow Interview page from Paused & Failed Flow Interviews I get something like this:

As you can see in the "current flow information" & "flow information" sections there is the version number, but when I look at the Orchestration run or Flow Interview records using Salesforce inspector these fields are nowhere to be seen.
Is there a possible way to find the version using SOQLs?
Thanks!

It looks like you've already found that the version number of a flow is visible on the Flow Interview page in the Salesforce UI, but not readily available through Salesforce inspector or standard queries. Unfortunately, Salesforce doesn't expose the version number directly in a queryable format through SOQL on the FlowInterview object itself.
However, there might be a workaround. You could use the Tooling API to query the FlowDefinitionView object, which can provide information about the flow versions. Here’s a SOQL query you could try using the Tooling API:
SELECT Id, ActiveVersion.VersionNumber, LatestVersion.VersionNumber, DeveloperName
FROM FlowDefinitionView
WHERE DeveloperName = 'Your_Flow_API_Name'

This will give you the active and latest version numbers of the flow, but you'll need the API name of the flow. Remember, since you're looking at orchestrations, the specific details might vary slightly depending on how the flows are set up in your Salesforce org.
If the Tooling API doesn't fit your use case, consider using Apex to programmatically access the flow metadata or log this as a feature request with Salesforce, as many developers find direct access to this data could be beneficial.
Let me know if this helps or if you have any other questions!

I don't need to know which is the most active version though - I need to know what version the interview is on as I can have many flow interviews and one might be on say version 57 while the current active version is 59. I do need this for the latter part to determine the latest version though so thanks for that haha

I guess I could stamp it in somewhere on the record I'm using at the time of creation so thanks for the idea!

Just to update - What I'm doing is that on the record i am attaching the orchestration to I'm stamping in the active version using the SOQL the answer suggests. Not exactly what I wanted but its a good workaround
